How can i skip generation of main class using openapi-generator
I am using OpenApi generator version 7.9.0(latest) to generate files for controllers and model. The command i am using to do so is:
openapi-generator generate -i apiSpec/spec.yaml -g spring -c oapi-config.json -o .
My config file looks like:
{
  "useTags": true,
  "delegatePattern": true,
  "interfaceOnly": false,
  "java": "17",
  "library": "spring-boot",
  "mainClassName": "someApplicaton",
  "invokerPackage": "com.someApplication",
  "generateApiDocumentation": true,
  "generateApiTests": false,
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
  "performBeanValidation": true,
  "useBeanValidation": true,
  "openApiNullable": true,
  "modelPackage": "com.someApplication.models.gen",
  "apiPackage": "com.someApplication.api.gen",
  "configPackage": "com.someApplication.config.gen",
  "disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent": false,
  "additionalProperties": {
    "serviceName": "someApplication"
  }
}

When i generate file, it looks like 
This has 3 files within api.gen package. one is api.java, one is controller and last is delegete.java.
The main file is always named as OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java, as openapi-generator might have removed support for mainClassName tag in config json file.
when i mark interfaceOnly tag as true, i get only controller file which is an interface and doesn't have Controller annotation.
I want to name my main class as i want and have Controller annotation also.
